# configure mercurial repository on reviewboard

Tags: mercurial, review-board

I've installed reviewboard (both in windows and linux), I successfully added an svn repository (i see the commits on the repo in `http://reviewboard.ourcompany.com/reviewboard/r/new/)`  but I can't figure out how to properly add a mercurial repo, I added it to the repo list but there i no way of getting the commits out of it.
I tried using as path:
1)the http address of the mercurial server (the address is correct)
2)cloning locally a bare repo from the http server

I couldn't find any tutorial on how to configure reviewboard with mercurial

Comment: I'm having trouble with this as well. Neither Mercurial nor Git work. Adding diff files is problematic as well as reivew-board tries to access the repo and fails.